# JSON and AJAX form not submitting

Tags: jquery, json, ajax

I don't why my invite function is not submitting. 
It's only the part where the user clicks invite. It doesn't do anything. Nothing is sent. When i click on Invite new user the popup works find. So this leaves me to believe that it has something to do with the sending process.

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
  $(function(){
    $('#add-user').click(function(){if($('.sharing').is(':visible')) $('.sharing').fadeOut(); else $('.sharing').fadeIn();});
    $('.sharing p.title .closesharing').click(function(){
        $('.sharing').fadeOut();
        $('#inviteuser').find('.row:last').find('.col-md-6').html('');
        document.getElementById('inviteuser').reset();
    });

    $('#inviteuser').find('.row:last').find('.col-md-6').html('');
    $(document).on('submit', '#inviteuser', function(){
        $('#inviteuser :submit').button('loading');
    });
    $('#inviteuser').ajaxForm({
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
            method: 'inviteuser',
            get_params_as_array : '1'
        },
        success: function(data) { 
            if(data.success == 1)
            {
                $('#inviteuser').find('.row:last').find('.col-md-6').html('<span class="text-success">An invitation has been sent</span>');
                setTimeout(function(){$('.sharing p.title .closesharing').click();}, 5000);
            }
            else
            {
                if(typeof data.errors != "undefined")
                {
                    var e = data.errors;
                    var textErr = '';
                    for(var index in e) { 
                        if(textErr != '')
                            textErr += ', ';
                        textErr += e[index];
                    }
                    $('#inviteuser').find('.row:last').find('.col-md-6').html(textErr);
                }
            }
            $('#inviteuser :submit').button('reset');
        } 
    }); 
});
```

```
 <section id="TT">
<div id="one"><img src="<?= base_url('public/images/mouse.jpg'); ?>" alt=""><br><p class="wblink1"><button id="add-user">INVITE NEW USER</button></p></div>
<div id="two"><img src="<?= base_url('public/images/cam.jpg'); ?>" alt=""><br><p class="wblink2">LIVE VIDEO CHAT</p></div>
<br>
<div id="one"><img src="<?= base_url('public/images/record.jpg'); ?>" alt=""><br><p class="wblink">RECORD A MESSAGE</p></div>
<div id="two"><img src="<?= base_url('public/images/white.jpg'); ?>" alt=""><br><p class="wblink">WHITEBOARD</p></div>
```

```
        <div class="sharing form col-md-8" style="display:none;" id="invite_member_form">
            <p class="title">Create User <span class="closesharing icon icon-close pull-right size-16"></span></p>
            <div class="col-md-12 pull-left ppls">
                <form id="inviteuser" action="<?=old_base_url('users/ajax')?>" method="post" name="newUser">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-8">
                            <p>Name <span class="mark_required">*</span>:</p>
                            <p><input type="text" name="params[name]" placeholder="Enter your invited user's name" required="" /></p>
                        <?php if(!empty($modules['library'])) { ?>  
                            <p>Role <span class="mark_required">*</span>:</p>
                            <p>
                                <select name="params[role]" required="" >
                                    <option value="" selected="selected" disabled="">select role</option>
                                    <option value="7" >Student</option>
                                    <option value="6" >Teacher</option>
                                </select>
                            </p>
                        <?php } ?>
                            <p>Email <span class="mark_required">*</span>:</p>
                            <p><input type="email" name="params[email]" placeholder="type email here" required="" /></p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-4">                  
                            <p>Add Personal Message</p>
                            <p><textarea name="params[message]" class="form-control" placeholder="Invite message"><?php $this->load->view('emails/invite',array('institute'=>$institute, 'current_user'=>$current_user))?></textarea></p>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-6 errors_ajax"></div>
                        <div class="col-md-5">
                            <p><input type="submit" class="submit" value="Invite!" data-loading-text="Loading..."></p>
                        </div>                      
                    </div>                        
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: `ajaxForm({` plugin or...?

Comment: im using this    <script src="http://malsup.github.com/jquery.form.js"></script>